# How to create Cron Job Hourly in Travis

Tags: travis-ci

I need to create Build Job in travis which triggers 1hourly or 2hourly .
i have seen option in Travis by daily,weekly and monthly.
Please give me advice in the same.

Answer (score 3):

Travis does not offer smaller intervals than daily for their "cron" builds. 
To achieve a similar effect you will have to run a cron locally that triggers a new travis build via their api client.

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure what Travis is, but generally you can use `@hourly` instead of `@daily` etc in `/etc/crontab`, or put your script in `/etc/cron.hourly` instead of `/etc/cron.daily`. The locations may be different depending on your Linux distro, but this is how it works in Ubuntu.